# A couple of questions about characteristic polynomials without any real roots.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given vector space $V$ finite over $\mathbb{R}$ and a linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$ whose characteristic polynomial is $P_T(x)=x^2+4x+5$

Questions:

1. What is $\dim(V)$?
2. Is T an isomorphism?

I think $\dim(V)=2$ simply because that's the highest degree in the polynomial, but there are no terms this polynomial can be divided into over $\mathbb{R}$, so I'm very confused.

As for T's isomorphism, I know it's bijective, because we're going $V \rightarrow V$ and invertible. It's also bounded because we're operating over a finite field. Is that correct?

Comment: 1. The degree of the characteristic polynomial is the dimension of the vector space. 2. Why bounded? Is this a question about functional analysis? And where do you see a finite field?

Comment: You are correct about the dimension. It is not a big deal that the characteristic polynomial has no irreducible factor over $\mathbb{R}$. Did you learn about eigenspaces? $T$ is indeed an isomorphism, but your argument is not very clear. Lastly, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a finite field. The vector space $V$, as you noted, has finite dimension over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Regarding 2, is zero an eigenvalue?

Comment: @KeiOh Does that mean that T has no eigenvalues? I did learn about eigenspaces, but I don't really understand them that well..

Comment: @Bernard Isn't V a finite field? It's a finite subset of $R^2$ .

Comment: You didn't say so in your post. You just said $V$ is ‘finite over $\mathbf R$’, which I interpreted as an ellipse for  ‘finite dimensional’ (as a vector space). Anyway $\mathbf R^2$ is not a field *per se* – you have to define a multiplication, with adequate properties.

Comment: @AlexOsheter $T$ has no *real* eigenvalues indeed. In any case, $V$ is not a finite field. Since you saw that $V$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$, you can identify $V$ to the space $\mathbb{R}^2$.